# MPAndroidChart - zoom not working when inside SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, swiperefreshlayout

I'm using MPAndroidChart library and I want to put the chart inside SwipeRefreshLayout but then it's not possible to zoom it by pinching the screen.
Any advices how to solve this?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ReadingsChartFragment">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/readings_chart_swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
            android:id="@+id/readings_chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>



</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can we know why You want put chart inside SwipeRefreshLayout?

Comment: I want to reload data on swipe down

Comment: So put chart inside normal Layout but add onSwipeListener and then refresh chart